# .NET recompile on change/save

Tags: .net

I am using `.NET Framework` where I have to kill the server and manually recompile each time I make a small change, which is kinda annoying and most of the time I forget to recompile, and wonder why things aren't working as they suppose to.

I am so used to `nodemon` for `NodeJS`, and wondering if `dotnet` has something similar.

Comment: What "server"?  What "small change" are you making and how are you executing it?  Normally when debugging in Visual Studio it doesn't *allow* you to edit compiled code while it's executing, which would eliminate the case of "forgetting to recompile".  What specifically is happening here?

Comment: I am using `visual studio code` and I have to recompile C# code by executing `dotnet run` each time I make a change. Even if I add console log, I have to kill the server and recompile. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you're using .NET Core, then I think this is what you're looking for: [dotnet watch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch)